# tex4ht fails with scrartcl class when defining \rm command. Argument of \popthree has an extra

Tags: koma-script, tex4ht

This MWE compiles OK with lualatex and pdflatex but fails with tex4ht. Why? And this happens only when using `scrartcl` and not with `article`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}%{article}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Now

```
 make4ht -ulm draft foo.tex
 ....
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/scrartcl.4ht
! Argument of \popthree has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.33 \:temp{rm}
?
```

I also tried

```
 \documentclass[11pt,enabledeprecatedfontcommands]{scrartcl}
```

But make4ht still gave same error.

Is there a workaround other than using `article`? I need to use `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}` for other things.

Using TL 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following version of `scrartcl.4ht` file:

```
% scrartcl.4ht (2015-02-07-15:56), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 1999-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2015 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2015-02-07-15:56}


\def\:temp#1#2#3{\DeclareOldFontCommand{#1}{\normalfont#2}{#3}}
\:temp{\rm}{\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\:temp{\sf}{\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\:temp{\tt}{\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\:temp{\bf}{\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\:temp{\it}{\itshape}{\mathit}

\input article.4ht
\Def:Section\minisec{}{#1}
\let\:minisec=\minisec
\def\minisec#1{\:minisec{#1}\@afterheading}
\pend:defI\@makefntext{\IgnorePar}

\Hinput{scrartcl}
\endinput
```

This version just defines old font commands and includes `article.4ht` file, where they are patched again. It seems that the patching of these commands in `article.4ht` is unnecessary and it should be safe to remove it. I need to investigate it more, but it looks like a really old hack.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Hope this fix will make it eventually to official source code for TL.

Comment: @Nasser yes, I am just fixing that, so it shouldn't take too long

Comment: @michal.h21 Got the same error, fixed it using this scrartcl.4ht file, so: have you ever included this into make4ht ?

Comment: @KeksDose do you get error with Nasser's example? It works for me with TL 2023. I think I had to remove the code from this answer because of some other errors. I've found this discussion, which is probably related: https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?529

Comment: @michal.h21 Sorry -- in the year 2015 you probably helped me with this issue here and I saved scrartcl.4ht in my ~/texmf tree and -- for good measure -- as well in the local-texmf tree. Found them there, deleted both, and now Nasser's example works. Will you attend to the TUG conference in July in Bonn? I owe you!

Comment: @KeksDose ah, this is the downside of local fixes :) unfortunately, I will not attend TUG, even if it is not that faw away from Prague :(